# InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString() returns different ip address

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` to String but it gets a different address. When I use `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`, I get my real IP address, but when I use `InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString()` it's some different address that I don't know.

This is my code:

```
  String ipAddr = StringUtils.substringAfter((String) InetAddress.getLocalHost(), "/");
  String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

My real IP address is 172.xxx.xxx.xxx, but when I convert to string, I get 168.xxx.xxx.xxx. How can I get my real IP address, that is, my IP address from my local machine?

Comment: What is actual output you receive in both cases?

Comment: @luk2302 my real ip adress starts with 172 and thats i get when i dont use conversion, but with conversion to string its starts with 192...

Comment: @luk2302 probably not - as OP clearly wants their external IP.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, they do seem to want the 172 address.